# Removed page_cache folder and admin cache page not working

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I removed the whole folder `var/page_cache` and now my admin page and cache page are not working anymore. I made a new folder page_cache but no difference. I can not refresh (no button anymore) and empty cache (noting happens when I push the button).

How can I build cache (because the site is also slow due to lack on full page cache) and make my admin cache page working again?

I use Magento 2.1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. IF you are using a language pack, for example netherlands you should run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL` as well

Comment: after above all commands give permissions as well and load site, your cache will create

Comment: My admin page is back with this commands, but the folder page_cache is stil not filled and the site is slow. I also use Redis, but this has no effect on the page_cache if i'm correct

Comment: you cache is enabled?

Comment: yep it is. When i inspect my env.php i see something strange. Are this the correct settings?  'cache' => array(
    'frontend' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => array(
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379'
            )
 ),
        'page_cache' => array(
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => array(
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'compress_data' => '0'